# Fiddler can easily decode responses - how to make this automatic?

Tags: fiddler

In Fiddler I have many responses which I like to view raw.  For each one Fiddler says "Response is encoded and may need to be decoded before inspection.  Click here to transform."

I want not only the current one, but all responses to always be transformed.  Anyone know how to set this?  Rules->Remove all encodings does not do the trick.

Comment: Well, the easiest way to automatically click stuff that is annoying would be [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: I would prefer a fiddler setting.

Answer (score 81):

If the goal is to remove compression *during* the processing of a session:

1. That's what the "Decode" button on the toolbar does.
2. That's also what Rules menu > "Remove all encodings" does.

[image: Auto decode]

If the goal is to remove the encoding *after* session processing is complete, select all of the sessions (CTRL+A) and use "Decode Selected Sessions" on the Web Sessions list's context menu.

Comment: I concur, this is what I was looking for as well.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: For me, I had it unchecked but Fiddler was decompressing every request anyway.  Toggling it on and off returned it to expected behavior.

Answer (score 9):

It's very easy. Just click the "Decode" button on Fiddler's toolbar.

Comment: This is the original answer. Basically, the solution provided by @EricLaw does not automatically decode all responses, you have to manually select responses and click on decode but the solution provided by Tank Xiao will automatically deocde all responses moving forward without manual intervention.

Comment: Both answers look identical to me except @EricLaw provided two ways to get to that option.

Comment: Is there a way to configure Fiddler to do this automatically instead of clicking it for each message?